# iOS: how to check if view has superView after animation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I had a very simple system where I could do

```
-(void)showMyView
{
    if (![self.myView superview]) {
        [self.view addSubview: self.myView ];
    }else{
        [self.myView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

But I needed to have animations so I change the code to

```
-(void)showMyView
{
    if (![self.myView superview]) {
        [self.view addSubview: self.myView ];
    }else{
        [self removeMyViewFromSuperView];
    }
}

-(void) removeMyViewFromSuperView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{self.myView.alpha = 0.0;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [self.myView removeFromSuperview]; }];
}
```

So presently the animation works, but the call `[self.view addSubview: self.myView ]` is no longer reachable. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you set self.myView to nil, then when you remove it from view hierarchy. That way you can just do

```
if (!self.myView) {
  //add your view
}
```

Comment: This would mean re-inflating the view from xib/nib each time I need to use it.

Comment: aah ok, so try doing self.myView.superview = nil explicitly! removing it from superview may not remove the references or you can check if your view has a window self.myView.window, that's another way to see if view is part of anything!

Comment: `self.myView.superview = nil` wouldn't work. You cannot assign to read-only properties. :)

Comment: oh yeah! i bet self.myView.window will work to check if it's part of view hierarchy. I have use that myself

Answer (score 0):

Your completion block won't trigger until the animation has ended (that is 0.5s).
In the remote case where you call showMyView while animating, you could do two things:

1. If you check the value of alpha is equal to 0. This will indicate that the animation is performing, since the properties of animations are changed inmediatelly (but you see the changes over time).
2. Have a flag (boolean) to indicate the state of removal

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is that the alpha of the view is still set to 0. So try the following when showing the view:

```
-(void) addMyViewToSuperView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{self.myView.alpha = 1.0;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [self.view addSubview: self.myView]; }];
}
```